# prevent redirection after submission

Tags: php, ajax

This form that I have gets redirected to "process_save.php" whenever I submit the form. What I want is to be able to still perform the function on "process_save.php" but not to redirect there after submitting a form. Rather, the form (which is inside a modal) be closed and reload the table that I have on a current page.

How can it prevent redirection after submission?

```
 <form id="form1" action="process_save.php" method="post">
....
</form>

$('form1').submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            url         : "process_save.php",
            data        : $(this).serialize(),
            encode      : true
        })
});
```

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: You probably want preventDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault() ;`

```
jQuery('#form1').on('submit',function(event) {
event.preventDefault() ;

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        dataType    : 'json',
        url         : "process_save.php",
        data        : $(this).serialize(),
        encode      : true
    })
});
```

Comment: i still got redirected to process_save.php

Comment: $('#form1').on('submit',function(event) {
event.preventDefault() ; @D.Gatch updated again

Comment: UPDATE removed action from form1 and it is now working. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove submit also, and use button to call ajax.

```
<form id="form1" action="process_save.php" method="post">
    ..... 
    <button type="Button" id="save">Save</button>
</form>

$('#save').click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            url         : "process_save.php",
            data        : $('#form1').serialize(),
            encode      : true
        })
});
```